# On the ring of real valued continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff set $X$.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, continuity, commutative-algebra, ideals

Assume X be a Hausdorff space and compact. Let $C(X)$ be the ring of real valued continuous function on X, where $f(x)+g(x) = (f+g)(x)$ and $f(x)g(x) = fg(x)$ be the ring's operations. Let $D$ be a dense open subset of $X$ and define $W(D) = \{f\in C(X) : f(D^c) = 0\}$. ($D^c$ is the complement of $D$, W(D) is an ideal of C(X)) Prove

1. The zero set of any ideal $I$ of $C(X)$ is nowhere dense.
2. For some $ f \in C(X) $, $f$ is not a zero divisor in $C(X)$ if and only if the zero set of $f$ is nowhere dense.

Here are my arguments but I couldn't go forward at some point and  really appreciate it if you could help me out.

My arguments:

1. Suppose $ A = \{x\in X:i(x) = 0~~\forall i\in I\} $ be the zero set of $I$. For any $i \in I$, since $ i(A) = 0 $, and $i$ is continuous, then $A$ is a closed set. Suppose $B \subseteq A$ be an open set. I think now I need to somehow show that $ B~\cap~D = \emptyset $ to get a contradiction, but I don't know how to approach it??
2. Assume $ f \in C(X) $ be a zero divisor in $C(X)$. Then $ f.g = 0 $ for some nonzero $g \in C(X)$. So, there is some $ x \in X $ such that $ g(x) \neq 0 $. Then I think I need to find an open neighborhood of $x$, say $B_x$ such that $g(B_x) = 0$ for any $ y \in B_x $. But I don't know how??(If it is a correct argument) For the other direction, I do not have any idea.

Thank you.

Comment: What's $W$ and what has $D$ to do with $W$?$D$ is a subset of $X$ or $C(X)$?Take $X$ to be the closed disc in the plane of radius 2,$A$ to be the closed disc of radius 1,isn't the set of functions vanishing in $A$ and ideal which is not nowhere dense?

Comment: @belkacemabderrahmane thanks for your comment, I have corrected the question. D is a dense subset of X. W(D) is an ideal of C(X).

Comment: but  the same  problem persists,Check the counterexample I gave u above. Maybe u mean Prove that the zero set of $W(D)$ is nowhere dense?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f$ is a zero divisor,then there is som nonzero $g$ such that $fg=0$ identically, since $g$ is nonzero,there is some $x\in X$ such that $g(x)\neq 0$,by continuity, there is a nbd $V\subset X$ such that $\forall v\in V;g(V)\neq 0$,So $\forall v\in V ,f(v)=0$, in particular the zero set of $f$ is not nowhere dense.
Now Suppose that $f$ is not a zero divisor,let $x$ be any zero of $f$,$U$ an arbitrary nd of $x$,suppose that $U$ is contained in the zero set ,choose an open subset $V$ such that $V\subset \overline{V}\subset U$,then there is a continous function(since a compact ahusdorff space is normal) with support inside $U$(apply Urysohn's lemma to the two disjoint closed subsets $\overline{V},U^{c}$) ,then u can see that $fg=0$ identically.

Comment: @rschwieb if $g(x)\neq 0$ not if $g(x)=0$,if a continous function does not vanish at point x, it does not vanish at a nbd of that point.

Comment: Sorry I clearly need a coffee!  You are right of course.